# How to use menu windows key in autohotkey?

Tags: windows, menu, keyboard, contextmenu, autohotkey

I am searching and searching. Please tell me is it possible to use menu windows key (location: next to right alt).

---

Found:

```
AppsKey - this is the key that invokes the right-click context menu.
```

Thanks for advance.
Thx for a help. ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think `{AppsKey}` is what you're looking for. Also check the [list of AHK keys](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm).